# Are all fractional derivative definitions wrong except Grunwald Letnikov definition?

Tags: improper-integrals, fractional-calculus

I'm trying to find out if there is a logical way to see which fractional definition is correct, so my attempt was as follows:

Suppose that we have the fact

$$\int_{0}^{\infty^{*}} \frac{\cos(ax)}{1-x^2}dx=\frac{\pi}{2} \sin(a) 
\ ,a>0$$

where the star above the integral is the Cauchy principle value integral.

Now Let's try to use differentiation under integral sign technique, so by differentiating both sides $p$ times with respect to a where $0<p\leq1$ using Grunwald definition
we will get:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty^{*}} \frac{x^p \cos(ax+\frac{\pi p}{2})}{1-x^2}dx=\frac{\pi}{2} \sin(a+\frac{\pi p}{2})$$
and we will get a correct result and this can be proved using Residue theorem or by using Laplace and Laplce inverse technique.

So my question is :
Is my approach correct? , does it mean that the other fractional derivative definitions are wrong?

Comment: In general, the differential of an integral is not the integral of the differential. And that is just for regular integrals (where it is often true.) Not sure what you’d need for the differential of a principal value of an integral to be equal to the principal value of the integral of the differential.

Comment: If f(x,a) is a continuous and continuously differentiable (i.e., partial derivatives exist and are themselves continuous) function then we can use the differentiation under integral sign technique

Comment: Is that true for principal values of integrals, though?

Comment: There is no “right” or “wrong” answer for a definition, of course. There is only “more useful” and “less useful.”

Comment: So,If you claimed that there is no wrong or no right definitions , you should prove your claim.

Comment: For example, there is one proved theomrem states that , No violation of lebniz rule no fractional derivative, and we can see alot of definitions which they  statisfy Lebniz rule, so that there are many wrong definitions.

Comment: I don't know who just upvoted your replies, in my opinion what you said is out of the logic, with my full respect for you and them

Comment: There is no reason to prove that there is no right or wrong definition, because it isn't a theorem. A definition is just a shorthand, so we don't have to say something over and over again. Does a ring have multiplicative identity or not? Some people define it one way, others another way. If you define fractional derivative one way, you have to be more precise when talking about any other definition. Things don't stop existing because we don't use them in definitions, we just stop using those particular words as shorthands.